# What's the proper term for this: "javascript object full of functions"?

Tags: javascript, object

I've been using this kind of programming pattern lately in order to group logically related functions:

```
FruitMethods = {
    url: "some/path/to/something.durk",
    get: function(data) {$.ajax(url, data)},
    delete: function(something) { some more function stuff....}
}
```

You get the picture right? It doesn't seem to really meet the definition of a Class... or does it? A Mixin? Something else? Javascript Object Full Of Functions And Maybe A Variable? JOFOFAMAV?

My vote if for JOFOFAMAV.

PS: Feel free to also chime in with your thoughts on whether or not this is a good practice.

Comment: I would call it an object. It is what it is. You probably already know it, but JavaScript has no classes. That said you can emulate them (logically).

Comment: maybe namespace/module is the word you're looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, it's an object with properties.  So, then your question becomes more about what common name would one call it.

Because it has no instance data and doesn't appear like one will be creating new instances of it (e.g. like a class), then it is most like a `namespace` which is just a named wrapper for a bunch of properties where properties can be any sort of data or functions.

Namespace objects are useful for a bunch of reasons:

1. Limiting the use of the top level, global namespace thus lowering the chance of a name conflict with other scripts.
2. An organizational structure/convention for collecting a group of related data or functions.
3. A hierarchical scheme that makes it easier for categorizing or organizing methods and/or data and referring to them with a simple scheme of `category.method` like `Fruit.get()`

Answer (score 1):

I would call that a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

That's a form of *singleton* - which is basically an object without an external definition: you don't have a 'class' definition and then create instances of that class.

One thing to know about this type of structure is that all of the methods of the object are public ( that may or may not be a problem).